# How to solve Ax = b for A

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

Given two know vector `x`, and `b` (dimension 3*1 for example), what are the ways to approximate the matrix `A` (dimension 3*3) so that the equality `Ax=b` is as close as possible (something like least square), knowing that very likely the system does not have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you actually do not have a system of linear equations that needs to be seen at a whole and solved together. Here you have 3 independent equations, each of them with infinite valid answers. So:

$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3}\\
a_{4} & a_{5} & a_{6}\\
a_{7} & a_{8} & a_{9}
\end{bmatrix}\times \begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\ x_{2} \\ x_{3} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b_{1}\\ b_{2} \\ b_{3} \end{bmatrix}$

equals solving

$a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} + a_{3}x_{3} = b_{1}$

and

$a_{4}x_{1} + a_{5}x_{2} + a_{6}x_{3} = b_{2}$

and

$a_{7}x_{1} + a_{8}x_{2} + a_{9}x_{3} = b_{3}$

independently.

Each of them in for example in $\mathbb{R}$ has infinite right answers. For instance in $a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} + a_{3}x_{3} = b_{1}$ you just need to randomly choose two of $a_{i}$s and simply get the last one. For example for known $x$ vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$, $b$ vector $\begin{bmatrix} 4\\ 5 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix}$ and $a_{1}=1$ and $a_{2}=2$, we get $a_{3}$:

$5 + 3\times a_{3} = 4$

so

$a_{3}=-\frac{1}{3}$!

Same procedure applies to other two equations as well. Randomly choose two $a_{i}$s for each equation and get the last one.

**PS:** I feel either something is missing in your question or I did not understand well. In either cases, please drop a comment here and I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Kasra. The system will likely not have an answer and should be approximated. Do you see a way to do this with a method like Least square ?

Comment: I still feel I am misunderstood. You again used the word "system". This is certainly not a system if A could be anything. If rows of A are related to eachother, then it is a system. But now, as I said in my answer, multiplying first row of A to x creates the first element of b regardless of rest of elements in A! I assume there are info about A that you did not include. For instance if rows of A are same variables, then you are basically finding the intersection of 3 planes.

Comment: As you mentioned there is no answer for this and according to my answer there is actually infnitely many, I feel like there is such constraint (like my previous comment) on A. In case of my previous comment, 3 planes might not have an intersection so the system has no answer and should be approaximated. I might be wrong but I think some info about A is missing in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As Kashra said, your "system" has an infinite number of valid solutions. However, there is one "canonical" solution, that might make more sense than others, depending what you are after.

A matrix is actually a way of writing down a linear operator. A linear operator transforms one vector into another, so when you say

$$
A \cdot x = b
$$

you are basically saying that $A$ performs a transformation on $x$, so that it becomes $b$. It is somewhat easier to visualise if we talk about 2D vectors (i.e. vectors in a plane) and $2 \times 2$ matrices. Transforming $x$ into $b$ means rotating and scaling it by a suitable angle and factor.

A rotation in 2D is given by the matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \varphi & -\sin \varphi \\
\sin \varphi &  \cos \varphi
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and scaling is simply multiplication by a scalar, say, $\lambda$. So your task of solving for $A$ reduces to finding $\varphi$ and $\lambda$.

Now, we know that dot product is

$$
a \cdot b = \left\lVert a \right\rVert \cdot \left\lVert b \right\rVert \cdot \cos \varphi
$$

from which you can derive $\varphi$. Scaling is even easier: to scale $a$ to be as long as $b$ you just need to multiply it by

$$
\lambda = \frac{\left\lVert b \right\rVert}{\left\lVert a \right\rVert}.
$$

For your 3D case it is a little bit more complicated, but the principle remains the same. You'll need to rotate along two axes, but scaling remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many solutions except in corner cases like x = 0 or something. In your case here, you could simply find a solution with $A = b x^+$ where $x^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. In R that would be something like `A = b %*% ginv(x)`, where `ginv` is from the MASS library.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment

> The system will likely not have an answer and should be approximated. Do you see a way to do this with a method like Least square`

Yes you can do that. The `Linear Regression` is done using this method.

If the `b` is not in the column space of `A`, to get an approximated solution, the vector `b` is projected onto the column space of `A`. Now with the new `b'` a solution of the system is found. This can also work if `b` is in the column space of `A` since its projection will be itself

Comment: In linear regression you solve for x given A and b. We have x and b here.